# Create Generic Names for Lots of Objects, Java

Tags: java

Heads up, I am a beginer so please ignore the fact that I have a limited vocabulary!

So I want to make a game of dominoes. I want to make each domino an object so I can know all the important information (like if it is on the board and if so then where) Basically the code would look like this if I were just creating the numbers for the domino:

```
for(int x = 12; x >= 0; x--)
{
  for(int y = 0; y <= x; y++)
  {
    Domino domxy = new Domino(x,y);
  }
}
```

Where "domxy" if x = 12 and y = 0, the name is dom120 giving each domino a unique name.

Comment: You probably want to store the dominoes in a 2D array, where x and y are your array indices. For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: One way would be to use a 2D array of `new Domino()`.

Comment: Would an array of `Domino`s work for you?

Comment: That was my first idea but I am not sure how to do this. Wouldn't they still need names? (my comp math teacher mentioned this solution but we ran out of class time XD)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a 2D array of Domino objects like this:

```
Domino[][] array = new Domino[x][y]
```

and assign every element like this:

```
array[x][y] = new Domino(x, y);
```

Comment: Ok so with this solution would it be possible to have different categories of dominoes like InHand, Boneyard, and OnBoard which are subclasses of Domino I failed to mention. With these classes I would have to be able to change the Boneyard domino to a InHand domino if the player drew it.

Comment: @SaigeHamblin This is not a very object-orientated solution, you could rather create classes for Boneyard and Hand which contain Objects of type Domino. Changing the classes of Objects at runtime is something I would not do in this case.

Comment: If all of your objects are subclasses then yes, u cant just delete old object, create new as subclass and set it to be under main class reference.